# Should one make one big textureatlas for all the images in the game, or a textureatlas for each screen?

Tags: java, libgdx

Title says it all actualy. Is it good if I pack all the images of the game into one textureatlas, or should I make a textureatlaswith the images needed for each screen. So like a textureatlas in main menu for the uiwidgets, a textureatlas for gamescreen with player images etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend splitting it by screen. You'll never be drawing from more than one Atlas at once (because only one screen is visible) but you can load only the textures you need into the graphics card.

Also, it'll make all the code and art creation more manageable.